# Can I set an Experiment using the Developer Console API?

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

I have many, many apps that all contain similar texts, in 30 languages. To do any change, I'm using the [Developer Console API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/).

Since a couple days ago, we decided to run a [Store Listing Experiment](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6227309?hl=en) on many of our apps, in every language. As you may expect, this is a pain, especially if we want to modify texts in many apps (times many languages): slow, prone to human errors, etc.

I haven't found any reference to the API regarding experiments, and I smell it will be in the end a pain but, just in case, is there a chance we can do so?